# Chrome browser select certificate dialog not handled by WebdriverIO

Tags: webdriver-io

I am trying to automate an application that uses Azure AD credentials for authentication, i am using webdriverio to enter the credentails but after successfully authentication Chrome browser presents dialog box to select the certificate with cancel and Ok button. And this dialog is not being handled even after many retries as mentioned below:

1. Chrome browser capabilties
   capabilities: [
   {
   // maxInstances can get overwritten per capability. So if you have an in-house Selenium
   // grid with only 5 firefox instances available you can make sure that not more than
   // 5 instances get started at a time.
   maxInstances: 5,
   //
   browserName: "chrome",
   "goog:chromeOptions": {
   args: ['--ignore-certificate-errors']
   /*    process.argv.indexOf("--headless") > -1
   ? ["--headless"]
   : process.argv.indexOf("--debug") > -1
   ? ["window-size=1440,800", "--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs"]
   : ["window-size=1440,800"] */

   ```
        },
        strictSSL: false,
        acceptInsecureCerts: true


        // If outputDir is provided WebdriverIO can capture driver session logs
        // it is possible to configure which logTypes to include/exclude.
        // excludeDriverLogs: ['*'], // pass '*' to exclude all driver session logs
        // excludeDriverLogs: ['bugreport', 'server'],
    }
   ```
2. Keyboard event to click on the ok button

devDependencies: {
"@wdio/cli": "^7.32.1",
"@wdio/local-runner": "^7.32.1",
"@wdio/mocha-framework": "^7.30.2",
"@wdio/spec-reporter": "^7.31.1",
"chromedriver": "^114.0.2",
"wdio-chromedriver-service": "^7.3.2",
"wdio-ui5-service": "^1.5.1"
},

I always get this error :"[chrome 114.0.5735.198 mac os x #0-0] Timeout of 60000ms exceeded. The execution in the test .Try to reduce the run time or increase your timeout for test specs (https://webdriver.io/docs/timeouts)".

Can anyone please help me out with this?

Regards,
Vikrant